# ExtJS 4.2.1 - Updating XTemplate after store load

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a bit of a weird situation...

I have a DataView that's backed by a store.  However, in the XTemplate, I'm trying to show the quantity of a certain type of JSON record.  Each record has a property value pair that denotes its type.  For example:

```
data: [
 { type: 'W' },
 { type: 'A' },
 { type: 'W' },
 { type: 'W' }
]
```

So there are 3 JSON objects of 'W' and 1 JSON object of type 'A'.  The number of 'W' should be displayed in the HTML element with the class 'total-pending'; 'A', in the HTML element with the class 'total-approved.'

My XTemplate:

```
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
        '<div style="text-align:center">Leave Requests</div>',
        '<table cellpadding="0" class="table-wrap">',
            '<tr>',
                '<td class="x-leave-request approved"><span class="total-approved">0</span>Approved</td>',
                '<td class="x-leave-request pending"><span class="total-pending">0</span>Pending</td>'denied">0</span>Denied</td>',
            '</tr>',
        '</table>'
    )
```

I've read a bit about templates and stores, but I can't seem to figure out how to update those numbers.  I tried to add a function callback to store.on('load', function{}) to change the HTML element via Ext.get(Ext.query('span.total-pending')[0]).update(3) but it had no effect..  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the hint that Oguz gave.  What I ended up doing was creating an Ext.util.Hashmap instance, whose  pairs were status type and total (e.g. <'W', 10>).  Then I called:

```
<tpl for=".">
 {[this.updateStatusTotal(values.type)]}
</tpl>

...

updateStatusTotal : function(type) {
 var me = this,
     map = me.map,
     total = map.get(type);

 map.put(type, ++total);
}
```

then later in the code where the `<td>` elements are, I call:

```
{[this.getStatusTotal('W')]}
```

Done :)

Comment: Easier way is just to call store.query('type', type).getCount().

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure will help your request but try and share result with us.

Try to make a function to count total values of W and A then call appropiate function inside the XTemplate via `this.function()`

```
tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
    '<div style="text-align:center">Leave Requests</div>',
    '<table cellpadding="0" class="table-wrap">',
        '<tr>',
            '<td class="x-leave-request approved"><span class="total-approved">{totalw:this.getTotalw()}</span>Approved</td>',
            '<td class="x-leave-request pending"><span class="total-pending">{totala:this.getTotala()}</span>Pending</td>'denied">0</span>Denied</td>',
        '</tr>',
    '</table>'
)
```